# How show function return with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<div id="final_total_amt"></div>
```

This is my js:

```
var final_item_total = 'Test!';
$('#final_total_amt').text(function(final_item_total) {
 return final_item_total;
});
```

I know this code works,

```
$('#final_total_amt').text(final_item_total);  // Out: Test!
```

But i want to show **'Test!'** the jQuery code with the **function(final_item_total)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defining a function in your `text` call. You can't do that. Define your function first:

```
function final_item_total_function() {
  var final_item_total = 'Test!';
  return final_item_total;
}
$('#final_total_amt').text(final_item_total_function);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return a `parameter`, the function will only print the parameter value. In your case, this is `undefined`  because you are not passing any parameter to the function when you are executing it.

To return a diferent variable you can just return it.

Check the following example:

```js
var final_item_total = 'Test!';

$('#final_total_amt').text(() => {
 return final_item_total;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="final_total_amt"></div>
```

You can also write it like this:

```
var final_item_total = 'Test!';

$('#final_total_amt').text(function() {
 return final_item_total;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
var final_item_total = 'Test!';
var result=getResult(final_item_total);
$('#final_total_amt').text(result);
function getResult(z){
 return z;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="final_total_amt"></div>
```